# imwheel Thumb1/2 (back/forward) actions not working

Tags: gnome, keyboard, mouse, 22.04, mouse-scroll

Due to the back/forward buttons in Discord doubling, I have tried to make it so that when I am focused on Discord, the back/forward buttons register as `Alt_L|Left`/`Alt_L|Right`, and when I am focused on anything else, it will just act like a normal back/forward button.

Here is my `.imwheelrc` file:

```
"^discord$"
    None, Up, Button4, 3
    None, Down, Button5, 3
    None, Thumb1,  Alt_L|Left
    None, Thumb2,  Alt_L|Right
```

Unfortunately, this causes the back/forward buttons on my mouse to completely stop working on any application which isn't Discord when I start imwheel using:

```
imwheel -b "4 5 0 0 8 9" -k
```

I have tried changing `.imwheelrc` to:

```
".*"
    None, Thumb1,  Button8
    None, Thumb2,  Button9

"^discord$"
    None, Up, Button4, 3
    None, Down, Button5, 3
    None, Thumb1,  Alt_L|Left
    None, Thumb2,  Alt_L|Right
```

To try and make it act normally when I am using any other application, but this just breaks it completely.

Even if I just try and set the `Thumb1/2` buttons to activate `Button8/9` on all applications including Discord, it still seems to not register any input from the back/forward button.

How can I make `imwheel` map `Thumb1`/`Thumb2` to the correct buttons on every window which isn't Discord?